# simple php multiple upload resize

Tags: image-uploading

I'm looking for a script that uploads and resizes multiple images using php.  I'm using a shared hosting so can't install things.  I had managed to upload, resize and watermark ONE image but really can't get it to work with multiple files.

Has anyone got something I could start with please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [ImageWorkshop](http://phpimageworkshop.com/), which is a good oop image manipulation library in pure PHP (GD), and supports multiple layer.

Simple loop through your files:

```php
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $layer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath($tmp_name);
    $layer->resizeInPixel(400, null, true);
    $layer->save($dirPath, $filename, $createFolders, $backgroundColor, $imageQuality);
}
```

More info in the [Quickstart](http://phpimageworkshop.com/quickstart.html).

Sure you can also write you own Image Library.

Comment: Thank you Christian, do you need special privileges to install ImageWorkshop? I've tried downloading the files, uploading them into my website and following the instructions but it doesn't do anything (no errors, nothing!). I get the idea I might need my own server rather than shared hosting, is that right? Thanks again.

Comment: No, it doesn't need something special then GD. And i have never seen a hoster with out GD. Try `error_reporting(-1);
`

Comment: Thank you very much for the info. I've managed to get it working and highly recommend it! Did you make the whole thing?

Comment: @GeneralTomfoolery, no, not created by me ;)